# how to save username and password in sqlite database in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am creating an iPhone application which makes use of SQLite. Only registered users are allowed to enter into my application. First a splash screen with a progress bar will be shown to the user that will check all the data from the SQLite database. If the user is not logged in, first he has to log in so that he can enter into the application. If he is already logged in, his credentials will be already saved in the database and accessed from there, and he can enter into the application. But I don't know how to save username and password in SQLite database. Please can anybody help me in solving this problem, or give any link that contains username/password storage in SQLite database.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

To store usernames/passwords, you generally use the keychain.
Take a look at this, and separate it from your SQLite database.

http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code